# Twig extend based on isxmlhttprequest

Tags: twig, silex

I'm using Twig with Silex and are having some trouble with extend within an if statement. Basically the page is being extended even tho, the request is not done by AJAX.

```
{% if app.request.isXmlHttpRequest == false %}
 {% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

However this works. The button is only being showed when the request is AJAX based.

```
{% if app.request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
{% endif %}
```

Also possibly worth mentioning my code is enclosed in an {% block content %} tag.

Does anyone have experience with this issue? (Being able to extend only if isXmlHttpRequest is false)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
{% extends app.request.isxmlhttprequest ? "" : "layout.html.twig" %}
```

Behind the courtains `extends` is a token parsed in a way that no conditions can be placed around it, the outcome will be what you got: your template is always extended.

I'm not sure how it'll work with the empty string, you may need to create a "layout-ajax.html.twig" file with no content but the block you want to override.

Comment: I just want to confirm that this works as well as the fact that you need to use a new template file with the empty blocks you are going to be using.

Comment: Yes, but right solution said @imkingdavid. 
In my case it is: `- extends app.json ? "layout.json.twig" :  "layout.html.twig"`